# complete html page not showing

Tags: html

i have a small html page in the following format

```
  <html>
     <head></head>
       <body>
         <div id="wrapper">
           <table></table>
         </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```

the problem I am having is that its not showing everything.. it scrolls down up to a point.. the background of it is a photoshop .png image and on top of that background i created the table within the div..

Everything else is in place and show appropiately, its just the end of the page is not showing.. doesnt scroll down completely.

The background at the end has a "Designed by [name]" but it is not showing this part.. it scrolls down up to just before this part of the png picture..

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: Can you provide us a link to look at or your css code please. Thanks.

Comment: We would need to see the whole code to figure out the problem.

Comment: background image scroll with contents, if you do not have any contents, so how its scroll.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a `min-height`.

Comment: that's like asking on a forum what you are hiding behind your back. Fixed height wrapper? absolute footer with bad placing? am i getting warm?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that.. i was about to post the all the code but then justin posted, i tried it and it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the limited information you provided, my guess is that the height of your page's content is not long enough to justify showing that part of the background. The page only scrolls to the length of the content, not the length of the background.

Fix the height of your wrapper `div` by making its `min-height` equal to the height of your image. Assuming your image is 500px in height, you CSS would be the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    min-height: 500px;
}
</style>
```